# Consultar últimos registros de uma tabela SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como realizar a consulta dos últimos trinta registros de uma tabela do banco de dados, contendo mais de um milhão de linhas, e ordena-los pelo código com uma boa performance?

```sql
SELECT* 
FROM (
  SELECT TOP 30 * 
  FROM Product 
  ORDER BY ID_Product Desc
) 
ORDER BY ID_Product Asc
```

Comment: Tente algo como: `SELECT TOP 30 * FROM PRODUCT ORDER BY ID_PRODUCT DESC`. O `DESC` indica que você deseja ordernar os registros em ordem decrescente e `TOP 30` indica resgatar os primeiros 30 registros.

Comment: Sugiro verificar o seu código na pergunta, pois o mesmo não funciona da forma que você colocou. também é importante utilizar as boas práticas para perguntas, para evitar receber negativos e conseguir respostas mais construtivas.

Comment: pq fazer um select na mesma tabela usando dois critérios de order by diferentes? isso não faz sentido... só existe nessa query uma tabela na realidade, que é "Product", primeiro faz um `order by ID_Product Desc`, a seguir, com esse mesmo resultado, que na prática é a mesma tabela, faz um `Order By ID_Product Asc`, isso não faz sentido algum, ou  o seu exemplo está incompleto e faltam outras tabelas. Do ponto de vista de sintaxe tem dois problemas ai: 1) há um parênteses a mais, segundo fora dos parênteses 2) falta um alias para a subquery, por exemplo `(select .....) PrimeiraQuery`

Comment: Se a coluna ID_Product for a chave primária, em índice clustered, a leitura é instantânea pois somente serão lidas sequencialmente as últimas 30 linhas, na ordem reversa (BACKWARD). E depois, ordernar as 30 linhas em ordem crescente é vapt-vupt.

Answer (score 1):

Está faltando informar a variável do seu SQL interno, que se torna uma View.

```
    (select top 30 * from Product Order by ID_Product Desc)
```

este código acima, se torna uma View dentro do seu select.

para torna-lo funcional, utilize uma variável após o fechamento dos parênteses.

```sql
    Select * 
        from (select top 30 * from Product  Order by ID_Product Desc) p 
        Order By ID_Product Asc
```

Comment: "Variável" -> "Alias"